# Upload a file using jQuery AJAX / Send additional data using the FileTransfer function

Tags: jquery, cordova

Having some real trouble with PhoneGap at the moment. Please correct me if what I'm trying to do here is impossible, or if I'm looking at this totally wrong.

Basically, I'm building an app that records the users voice before uploading the file to the server. I've managed to send the file off to the server no problem, but I also want to pass on a few additional parameters that will be helpful for when I put the data into a database.

Effectively, this is the process I'm trying to achieve:

1. User records voice, the voice file is assigned a randomly generated name and is saved onto the SD card.
2. The file is then transferred to a PHP file on the server, along with the temp file name.
3. The file is moved to an /upload directory, with the same name it was uploaded with.
4. The server sends a response back to Phonegap, notifying the application that the upload is complete.
5. The app then changes the content using the DOM, and loads up an audio player to play the most recent file (as the file will have the same name as it was uploaded with, it will not need any kind of data response from the server, just a notification).

I've tried mashing both AJAX and FileTransfer functions together (which obviously didn't work, as It's accessing the upload.php file twice with different data each time). Is there a way of perhaps passing on (and sub sequentially receiving) data from the File Transfer method, or even a way of passing a file over using jQuery AJAX?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be attaching success and fail callback functions to your `FileTransfer.upload` method, see here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

In the 'Quick Example' on that page, the win function is the success callback. In your `win` function (eg, the successCallback that gets called when the file upload was successful), you can then add the code to change the DOM and spin up an audio player. Since the filename will not have changed, you can just store that filename in a variable.

I'm not sure what jquery-ajax has to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added jQuery Ajax because I want to associate the uploaded file with a user ID. However, I'm unsure how I'm able to pass the user ID value through to the PHP file in order to add it to the database alongside the audio file. I wondered if there was a way of handling all of this purely with jQuery Ajax. Thanks again for replying.